# An algorithm to predict one of two values based on a linear model

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I would like to run by you an algorithm for predicting one of two values from a testing data set, based on a linear model applied to a training set. Please let me know whether this algorithm makes sense, whether it can be improved and whether there is already a well established algorithm to accomplish the same result, possibly already encapsulated in some R routine.

Given: Two dataframes, `training` and `testing`, comprising two columns: `Y` and `X`, in this order. The `Y` columns of both dataframes take values in the set {2,3}.

Assignment: Predict `testing$Y` from `testing$X` based on a linear model with coefficients obtained from the linear regression `training$Y ~ training$X`.

Suggested solution (R based pseudo-code):

1. `m <- lm(Y ~ X, data = training)`
2. `p <- predict(training, new_data = testing, interval = "prediction")`
3. for every row of `p` do as follows:
4. `if p$upr <= 2 or (p$lwr <= 2 < p$upr) or p@fit <= 2, then set p$fit <- 2`
5. `else if p$lwr >= 3 or (p$lwr < 3 <= p$upr) or p$fit >= 3, then set pfit <- 3`
6. `else set p$fit <- round(p$fit)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Ordinary Least Squares to model/predict TRUE/FALSE variables. Use a logistic regression to model whether or not the response is 3 (as opposed to 2) instead. In R:

```
> set.seed(1)
> training <- data.frame(Y=sample(c(2,3),size=20,replace=TRUE),X=rnorm(20))
> testing <- data.frame(X=rnorm(10))
> model <- glm((Y==3)~X,data=training,family="binomial")
> predicted.probability <- predict(model,newdata=testing,type="response")
> predicted.probability
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
0.3878517 0.5758582 0.5125030 0.5696074 0.7251828 0.6150541 0.6124945 0.5703115 0.4203187 0.4636143 
> prediction <- c(2,3)[(predicted.probability>0.5)+1]
> prediction
 [1] 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2
```

Look at `?glm` (note the `family` argument) and `?predict.glm` (note the `type` argument), and read up on [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Comment: Thank you. This is very illuminating. But what if the `Y` column takes values in a bigger, but still finite, set, such as {1,2,3,4,5}. Will the above code still work?

Comment: No, it won't (it will only classify between "3" and "non-3"). In that case, you need [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression); for R, [look here](http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm). Or you could start looking at nonlinear classification methods, like classification trees or [Random Forests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest), with the `randomForest` package in R.